# What does curly braces inside parentheses mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js

I'm relatively new to javascript and I'm learning VueJS.. When initiating a new vue object I realized the code is similar to this:

```
new Vue({
    el: ‘#app’,
    data: {
        title: ‘hello World’
    }
});
```

I know from working with js objects is that we can initiate objects with curly braces like this:

```
var car = {
   type: "Fiat", 
   model: "500", 
   color: "white"
};
```

and I also know that parentheses are used for functions and we can have curly braces inside parentheses like so:

```
connect({ name: "testing" });
```

but the next notation in vue confused me because I know vue is an object not a function so I dont know why there are paranthesis, can someone clarify this part to me:

```
new Vue({});
```

Thank you.. Any reply is appreciated

Comment: The empty curly braces represent an empty object. You're passing in to the constructor an empty object.

Comment: It's exactly the same usage as `connect({name: "testing"})`…

Comment: Dear Maya, while there's a simple answer to your question, I prefer suggesting an advice. It seems that you lack very basic knowledge about the JavaScript language, and I guess your trying to learn by reading code. That is like deciphering an ancient and forgotten language, but there's a better path you can take... Choose one of the myriad of "Learn JavaScript" resources (online reading, videos, a book, etc.) and start from the basics. It will do you much better than working so hard too understand on your own... Good luck!

Comment: @deceze but connect is a function and new Vue({}) is not a function so thats why am confused..  Is there a syntax like this in javascript to creating objects?

Comment: Object constructors *are* functions. If you've ever instantiated *any* object, you may have noticed that you can pass arguments to it; e.g. `new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')`.

Comment: As @deceze mentioned, when you call new Vue() you are calling the constructor, which is a function. Have a read on this link: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) so you can have a better understanding how constructors works

Answer (score 2):

Yep - just the same as your usage here:

```
connect({ name: "testing" })
```

`new` signifies a constructor, which is called like a function, so you use parentheses. And the Vue constructor expects an object, which is signified by the curly braces. So this:

```
new Vue({})
```

Means you're passing no options to the Vue constructor.

If you're confused about why Vue "isn't a function", then it's because using `new` with the name of a class constructs an instance of that class. If you're using an ES5-style constructor function:

```
function Construction(option) {
  this.option = option;
}
```

Then it's fairly obvious how that happens. Class constructors are a little different, but there's no difference whatsoever in how they're created - just like a function call. And like any function, you can pass an object.

Comment: Oh I see, so basically what we're doing is passing an object to the Vue Constructor.. That explains it.. I have another question: u know how when we created a vue object we wrote new Vue etc.. in the object passed to the constructor we did not specify what type that object is; I mean what class are we creating that object from so now I'm wondering what type of object we're passing to the vue object..

Comment: Yep, that's it @maya91!

Comment: @maya91 JS has no object types. That's the beauty and the curse of JS. You have unlimited possibilities but you have to rely heavily on the documentation of others. E.g. what are all possible options you can input into the Vue constructor? You have to look it up!